# Import Error :Cannot import name db

Tags: python-2.7

This is the error am having when I am trying to use "python manage.py dropdb" in this course at https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/flask-micro-framework-introduction/table-of-contents.
The code is exact but am having this import error whenever I run the command above.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from thermos import app,db
  File "/Users/tunji/dev/thermos/thermos/thermos.py", line 7, in <module>
    import models
  File "/Users/tunji/dev/thermos/thermos/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from thermos import db
```

This is my thermos.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for, flash,redirect

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from forms import BookmarkForm
import models

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir,'thermos.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def new_bookmarks(num):
    return []

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',new_bookmarks=models.Bookmark.newest(5))

@app.route("/add",methods=['GET','POST'])
def add():
    form = BookmarkForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.url.data
        description =form.description.data
        bm = models.Bookmark(url=url,description=description)
        db.session.add(bm)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Stored '{}'".format(description))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('add.html',form=form)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'),404

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'),500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

and my manage.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from thermos import app,db
from flask_script import Manager,prompt_bool

from thermos import db
from models import User

manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def initdb():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(User(username='olatunji',email='ayo19602003@yahoo.com'))
    db.session.add(User(username='ayobami',email='bambamaks37@gmail.com'))
    db.session.commit()
    print "Initialized the database"

@manager.command
def dropdb():
    if prompt_bool(
        "Are you sure you want to lose all your data"):
        db.drop_all()
        print 'Dropped the database'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

This is the directory structure:

```
./thermos:
__init__.py manage.py   static      thermos.py
forms.py    models.py   templates   thermos.pyc
forms.pyc   models.pyc  thermos.db

./thermos/static:
css img js

./thermos/static/css:
main.css        normalize.css       normalize.min.css

./thermos/static/img:

./thermos/static/js:
main.js vendor

./thermos/static/js/vendor:
jquery-1.11.2.min.js            modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js

./thermos/templates:
404.html        add.html        form_macros.html
500.html        base.html       index.html
```

How can I solve solve this error in traceback?Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I made this little adjustment to my thermos.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for, flash,redirect

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from forms import BookmarkForm


app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir,'thermos.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

import models

def new_bookmarks(num):
    return []

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',new_bookmarks=models.Bookmark.newest(5))

@app.route("/add",methods=['GET','POST'])
def add():
    form = BookmarkForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.url.data
        description =form.description.data
        bm = models.Bookmark(url=url,description=description)
        db.session.add(bm)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Stored '{}'".format(description))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('add.html',form=form)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'),404

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'),500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```